# MySQL Exception in asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, web-applications

I tried a login page in visual studio 2017 asp.net c# web application using MySQL and it shows the following error:

> Line 33:queryStr = "SELECT * FROM webapp.userregistration WHERE
>   username='" + usernameTextBox.Text+ "'AND password='" +
>   passwordTextBox.Text; Line 34: cmd = new
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(queryStr,conn); Line 35:reader =
>   cmd.ExecuteReader(); Line 36:              Line 37:             name =
>   "";
>
> Source File:
>   C:\Users\HOME\source\repos\WebPage\WebPage\default.aspx.cs    Line: 35
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax at line 1]
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket() +309
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow,
>   Int64& insertedId) +67
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32&
>   affectedRows, Int64& insertedId) +17
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean
>   force) +110    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
>   +875    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) +1688    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
>   +6    WebPage._default.Submit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\HOME\source\repos\WebPage\WebPage\default.aspx.cs:35
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9782450
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +204
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +12
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +35    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1639

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System;
using System.Data;

using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace WebPage
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd;
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader reader;
        String name;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DoSQLQuery();
        }

        protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            String connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebAppConnString"].ToString();
            conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connString);
            conn.Open();
            String queryStr = "";
             queryStr = "SELECT * FROM webapp.userregistration WHERE username='" + usernameTextBox.Text+ "'AND password='" + passwordTextBox.Text;
            cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(queryStr,conn);
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            name = "";
            while (reader.HasRows && reader.Read())
            {

                {
                    name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("username")) + " " + reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("password"));
                }

                //if the data matches the rows (username, password), then you enter to the page
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    Session["uname"] = name;

                    Response.BufferOutput = true;
                    Response.Redirect("login.aspx", false);

                }
                else
                {
                    passwordTextBox.Text = "invalid user";

                }
            }

            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }


        private void DoSQLQuery()
        {
            try
            {

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                passwordTextBox.Text = e.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

string on the query side have the error and dangerous at the same time [look here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

your query output

> SELECT * FROM webapp.userregistration WHERE username='admin'AND
>   password='12345

last char not exist '

```
cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM webapp.userregistration WHERE username = @name  and password=@pas", conn);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", usernameTextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pas", passwordTextBox.Text);
```